# Palindrome Checker

Tags: c

I have been given the following assignment:

> Write a program which takes a string as input and prints the longest
>   prefix of the string whose reverse is a valid suffix of the string.
>   For example, if "notation" is given as input, the prefix "no" is the
>   longest prefix that has a matching valid suffix (namely "on") at the
>   end.
>
> If a string is a palindrome (i.e. if the string is the same as its
>   reverse), then the prefix is the whole string itself. For example, if
>   input is "civic", then the longest prefix is "civic" itself. If the
>   string has no valid prefix, print 0. For example, if the input string
>   is "bird", there is a mismatch at the first character itself and there
>   is no valid prefix.
>
> The symbols in the string will only be from the set {A-Z,a-z}. The
>   symbols are case sensitive. i.e. ‘A’ and ‘a’ are considered to be
>   different.   You are provided with a function called printChars ( )
>   that prints a character array from the starting position pointed to by
>   p to the ending position pointed to by q. If p is NULL, it prints 0.
>
> The prototype of the function is:
>
> ```
> void printChars(char *p, char *q);
> ```
>
> You do not have to write the program for printChars ( ) function. This
>   function is automatically added at the end of the code segment that
>   you write.
>
> You can use string functions in the library if you desire to.
>
> INPUT: Input is a string of length N composed of symbols only from the
>   set {A-Za,z}.
>
> OUTPUT: The longest prefix that has a corresponding matching suffix
>   and 0 if such a prefix does not exist.
>
> CONSTRAINTS: The inputs will satisfy the following properties. It is
>   not necessary to validate the inputs.
>
> 1<=N<=99

I have written code but compilation failed. What might be causing the problem and how do I resolve it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void printChars(char *p,char *q);
int main()
{
    char a[99];
    int n;
    scanf("%s",a);
    char *p=null,*q=null,*x;
    p=&a[0];
    q=&a[0];
    n=strlen(a);
    x=&a[0]+(n-1);
    for(int i=0;i<=(n-1);i++)
    {
        if(*x==*q)
        {
            x--;
            q++;
        }
        else
        {
            q--;
            break;
        }
    }
    x=&a[0]+(n-1);
    if(*p!=*x)
        printf("0");
    printchars(p,q);
    return 0;
}

void printChars(char *p, char *q)
{
    if (p==NULL){
        printf("0");
    }
    else{
        while(p <= q){
            printf("%c",*p);
            p++;
        }
    }
```

still getting an error

```
Program:52:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
Program:52:1: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'printChars' [enabled by default]  
Program:52:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]  
Program:52:1: error: conflicting types for 'printChars'  
Program:34:6: note: previous definition of 'printChars' was here  
Program:54:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'return'  
Program:56:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token  
Program:59:6: error: redefinition of 'printChars'  
Program:34:6: note: previous definition of 'printChars' was here
```

Comment: Why not indent the code?

Comment: And does the code supplied compile?

Comment: If the code doesn't compile, please include the errors you get.

Comment: Above I have written error..

Comment: You're missing the capital 'C' in your call to printChars().

Answer (score 2):

There is no predefined macro named `null` in C.
Change

```
char *p=null,*q=null,*x;
```

to

```
char *p = NULL, *q = NULL, *x;
```

Change function call

```
 printchars(p,q);  
      ^ This 'c' should be in capital
```

to

```
 printChars(p,q);
```

Also you missed a closing brace `}` for the function `printChars`.
And then finally your running code: http://ideone.com/SczMu2

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<string.h>
 void printChars(char *p,char *q);//function prototype
  int main()
 {

  int i,n,k=0,j;
  char a[100];
  char b[100];
  char *p;
  char *q;
  printf("enter array of chars");
  scanf("%s",a);
  n=strlen(a);
  j=n;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
       b[j-1]=a[i];

       j--;
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
       if(a[i]==b[i])
       {k++;
       p=a;}
       //printf("%c",a[i]);
       else if(a[i]!=b[i]&&k==0){
       p=NULL;break;}
       else break;
    }
    //p=a;
     q=&a[k-1];



    printChars(p,q);
   return 0;
 }//end of main
  void printChars(char *p, char *q)
 {
   if (p==NULL){
 printf("0");
   }
   else{
   while(p <= q){
     printf("%c",*p);
   p++;
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a close to similar assignment for about a year ago.

Look at this Function. It returns the number of how many chars to print from the word.

```
int palindromeWordIndex(char *str)
{
    int indexLeft = 0, indexRight = strlen(str)-1;

    while (indexLeft <= indexRight)
    {
        if (str[indexLeft] == str[indexRight]){
            indexLeft++;
            indexRight--;
        }
        else
            return indexLeft;
    } 
    return strlen(str);
}
```

I remaked it from my own function that only checks if a word is a palindrome.

```
int isPalindromeIter(char *str){
int indexLeft = 0, indexRight = strlen(str)-1;

while (indexLeft <= indexRight){
    if (str[indexLeft] == str[indexRight]){
        indexLeft++;
        indexRight--;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
return 1;
```

}